# v-img: require('../img/book.png') is a module and can't be loaded

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I have a following line in a SFC:

`<v-img :src="require('../img/book.png')"></v-img>`

I get an error:

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, Object, got Module`

In webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
},
{
  test: /\.vue$/,
  loader: 'vue-loader',
  options: {
    transformAssetUrls: {
      'v-img': 'src',
    }
  }
},
```

I'm not using Vue CLI. I'm managing Webpack config myself.

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI with Vuetify CLI plugin or are you managing Webpack config yourself?

Comment: If you try to find `transformAssetUrls` in it, does it exist ?

Comment: @MichalLevý Yes, it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `:src="require('../img/book.png')"` to `src="../img/book.png"` and add the following to webpack.config.js:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
plugins: [
  new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'src/img', to: 'img' },
      ],
  }),
]
```